# How to pic only duplicate values based on 2cols in pandas df?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have df like this:

```
df1:
    PL IN
    22 NE22
    22 NE22
    22 NE22
    33 DE33
    33 DE33
    66 NL66
    66 NL66
    66 NL66
```

I need to save csv with only unique value so the result should be:

```
    22 NE22
    33 DE33
    66 NL66
```

I know `.unique()` method but it works only on Series (?) I need to pic 2 col. Can someone give me an advice?

Comment: Usel `df.drop_duplicates(['PL', 'IN'])`

Comment: @RenéHöhle Thanks for the suggestion, but in that post is list hardcoding and only loops in core python. I hoped to answer as Erfan one. I didn't know that func. Thank U!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the duplicates then write to csv.

```
df1 = df1.drop_duplicates(subset=['PL', 'IN'], keep='first')
df1.to_csv('my_unique_csv.csv', index=False)
```